# Noticed something weird in derivation of relationship between ICBO and ICEO in BJTs

Tags: bjt, semiconductors

So I'm currently studying Electronic Devices and Circuit Theory by Boylestad and Nashelsky (11th ed.) and I'm confused as to how the relation between \$I_{CEO}\$ and \$I_{CBO}\$ is derived.
So the derivation in the book starts with the equation
$$I_C = \alpha I_E + I_{CBO}\ \tag1$$
But since \$I_E = I_C + I_B\$ ,
$$I_C = \alpha (I_C + I_B) + I_{CBO}\ \tag2$$
Rearranging yields
$$I_C = \frac{\alpha I_B}{1-\alpha} + \frac{I_{CBO}}{1-\alpha}\ \tag3$$
Then it goes on to say that \$I_C\$ when \$I_B = 0\$ is assigned the notation \$I_{CEO} = \frac{I_{CBO}}{1-\alpha} \approx \beta I_{CBO}\$ which is consistent with other sources.

The weird thing I noticed is that letting \$\alpha I_E = I_C\$ in eq. 1 produces
$$I_C = I_C + I_{CBO}\ \tag4$$
and letting \$ \frac{\alpha I_B}{1-\alpha}=\beta I_B = I_C\$ in eq. 3 produces
$$I_C = I_C + \frac{I_{CBO}}{1-\alpha}\ \tag5$$
which are surprisingly not the same in addition to being paradoxy/fallacious... So my question is what went wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The original equations are:
$$I_C = \alpha I_E + I_{CBO} \tag{a}$$
$$I_C = \beta I_B + (\beta +1)I_{CBO} \tag{b}$$

Before equation 4, you mentioned that \$\alpha I_E = I_C\$. But this is valid only when \$I_{CBO} = 0\$ and that is what equation 4 says.

In the same way, \$I_C = \beta I_B\$ is valid only if \$I_{CBO} = 0\$ and that is what equation 5 says.

Both equation 4 and 5 are valid only under the approximation that \$I_{CBO} = 0\$.